# export each and every data to excel sheet or any format

Tags: c#, asp.net, export-to-excel

I have to export each and every  data to excel sheet or ant format like pdf,word,etc.. How can i do(write data to any format)...i have dispalye data in html ..i have to export in word or any format.

public void Function(string fname)
{

```
strhtmlcontent.Append("<div id='id1'><table align='Center' style='background-color:Silver' BORDER-COLLAPSE:collapse cellSpacing=0 rules=all border=1 width='100%'><th width=8%>FirstName</th><th width=15%>Product Name</th><th width=15%>Client Name</th><th width=10%>Amount</th><th width=15%>Activity Date</th>");

SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

scon.Open();
if (fname == "All")
{
    scmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT usermaster.firstname, Product_Master.product_name, Product_Master.client_name, Product_Master.amount, Product_Master.activity_date FROM usermaster INNER JOIN Product_Master ON usermaster.product_id = Product_Master.product_id", scon);
}
else
{

    scmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT usermaster.firstname, Product_Master.product_name, Product_Master.client_name, Product_Master.amount, Product_Master.activity_date FROM usermaster INNER JOIN Product_Master ON usermaster.product_id = Product_Master.product_id where firstname='"+fname+"'", scon);

}
 dr = scmd.ExecuteReader();       




string firstname = "", product_name = "", activity_date = "";

string client_name = "", amount = "";

while (dr.Read())
{
    firstname = dr["firstname"].ToString();
    product_name = dr["product_name"].ToString();
    client_name = dr["client_name"].ToString();
    amount = dr["amount"].ToString();
    activity_date = dr["activity_date"].ToString();


    strhtmlcontent.Append("<tr><td align='center'>" + firstname + "&nbsp;</td><td align='center'>" + product_name + "&nbsp;</td><td align='center'>" + client_name + "&nbsp;</td><td align='center'>" + amount + "&nbsp;</td><td align='center'>" + activity_date + "&nbsp;</td></tr>");


}

dr.Close();
strhtmlcontent.Append("</table></div>");
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(strhtmlcontent);       
HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
//HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

}

Comment: You can always use crystal reports and export the result set to PDF... See this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14597/Convert-a-Crystal-Report-to-PDF or this here http://vb.net-informations.com/crystal-report/vb.net_crystal_report_export_pdf.htm

Comment: I know using crystal i can do that but requirement is above ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using ADO.NET**

Connection String should be this way:-

```
string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Book1.xls;Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;""";
```

## Example:

```
DbProviderFactory factory =   DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.OleDb");

using (DbConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection())
{
    connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;

    using (DbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Cities$] (ID, City, State) VALUES(4,\"Tampa\",\"Florida\")";

        connection.Open();

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Refer **[Reading and Writing Excel Spreadsheets Using ADO.NET C# DbProviderFactory](http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/05/26/2973.aspx)**

Comment: when i run my page its getting data  exactly like in database... yes i want to export same data(not html) to any format from my webpage just like it shows on on browser..

Answer (score 1):

Are you OK to use some commercial library? You can try XlsIO, PdfIO, DocIO from Syncfusion.

http://www.syncfusion.com/products/reporting-edition